# What does func?.Invoke() mean?

Tags: c#

Hey I was writing some timer functions (like JS setTimeout) and when invoking `endFunc` I checked:

```
if(endFunc!= null) endFunc();
```

and VS2017 proposed `endFunc?.Invoke()`. I suppose, there is no difference, but what exactly does `?.` means there? Can I use it in other cases like `myString?.SubString()`?

Comment: "Can I use it in other cases like myString?.SubString()?" Why not try it out?

Comment: it is [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (so called `Elvis operator`)